# Quand on utilise « c'est » quel est le sujet de la phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, démonstratifs, sujet

Quand on commence une phrase par « **c'est** », normalement structurellement ce n'est pas une phrase ordinaire. Car une phrase simple commence par un sujet.

Si on prend l'exemple suivant :

> Je vous recommande vivement la Spaghetti Bolognaise dans ce restau. C'est très délicieux et bien épicé !

Cette phrase contient plusieurs fautes, n'est-ce pas ? Est-ce que vous pouvez me corriger la deuxième partie de cette phrase sachant qu'elle est dans un contexte professionnel.

Comment: "spaghetti" en italien est pluriel. Je suppose que tu parles d'un plat dont le nom est "Spaghetti Bolognaise".

Comment: ou c'est ce qui est écrit dans le menu au restaut :)

Comment: *(parenthèse culinaire)* Epicé ? Il y a beaucoup de recettes accomodant les spaghetti avec diverses sauces épicées, mais une chose est sûre : la bolognaise n'en fait pas partie ! Ca me semble aussi bizarre que de dire *ils sont délicieux et bien sucrés !* ou *ils sont délicieux et bien crêmeux !*

Comment: Pourtant il y avait de bons épices dans les spaghettis Bolognaise

Comment: It’s not your question or point I know, but don’t ever be too quick to judge the quality of a restaurant by its transplanted chef’s command of his/her second (or maybe 3rd or 4th) language. “Bien epicé” could easily come from a flawed translation of “well spiced”/”well seasoned”= “bien assaisonné” and as long as I’m getting more than just one strand of spaghetti, I don’t care how it’s spelled  as long as it’s très délicieux!

Comment: @PapaPoule I'm not judging the quality of this restaurant. I'm just pointing out some possible mistranslation of *tasty / well seasoned* with *épicé* in french, which often means *spicy / hot*, and such a difference seems quite big to me ^^ Many people could be turned off by what they think will be too hot a plate for them, when there's actually no "hotness" here at all... I'd advise to use *finement assaisonnés* instead of *bien épicés*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ma réponse va surement reprendre plusieurs réponses déjà faites, le but étant de répondre à l'ensemble de ta question.

---

Ta **première interrogation** à propos des phrases commençant par *"c'est*" nécessite de comprendre ce que signifient ces deux mots. Comme l'a indiqué @Circeus, le *c'* correspond à [*cela*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cela) et fait référence à ce dont on parle, déterminé par la ou les phrases précédentes.

Cela peut être le sujet ou un complément voire une phrase entière, il n'y a pas de règle, il s'agit de donner plus d'information sur un élément du discours.

C'est donc un [pronom](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pronom) :

> Mot-outil qui peut prendre la place d’un syntagme nominal.

Et donc qui peut être sujet; ici du verbe être.

---

Concernant tes deux phrases, il y a en effet plusieurs fautes que je vais faire mon possible pour corriger.

> Je vous recommande vivement la Spaghetti Bolognaise dans ce restau. C'est très délicieux et bien épicé !

Tout d'abord dans **la première phrase**,

> Je vous recommande vivement la Spaghetti Bolognaise dans ce restau.

plusieurs formulations sont possibles. Sachant que tu nous parles d'un milieu professionnel, comme l'indique @Elyasin, tu devrais utiliser le mot entier (restaurant).

Pour le plat de [spaghettis](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/spaghetti), tu peux dire

> Je vous recommande les spaghettis bolognaise

ou

> Je vous recommande les spaghettis dans leur sauce bolognaise

ou

> Je vous recommande les spaghettis, la bolognaise est exquise

mais pas *"la Spaghetti Bolognaise"* car *"spaghetti"* est masculin et que ce sont des noms communs et donc qu'il n'y a pas besoin de majuscule.

**La seconde phrase** :

> C'est très délicieux et bien épicé !

Le *"C'"* peut faire référence au plat de spaghettis, ou, si il y a d'autres phrases avant ces deux dernières parlant du restaurant et de ses plats, peut être une conclusion et faire référence à l'ensemble des plats du restaurant.

On ne peut utiliser [délicieux](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9licieux) qui a un sens de [plaisir extrême](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9lices) avec le mot [très](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tr%C3%A8s) qui sert justement à augmenter la force de l'adjectif. Il n'y a pas plus haut qu'un maximum ou, autrement dit, il n'y a pas meilleur qu'un délice.

Tu devrais plutôt dire :

> C'est délicieux et bien épicé

ou pour conserver l'idée d'un *très* bon repas

> C'est délicieux et *très* bien épicé

---

N'ayant pas plus d'information sur le contexte du milieu professionnel dont tu parles, je ne peux te dire comment formuler tes phrases. Inspire toi des autres réponses et marque comme acceptée celle qui répond le mieux à ce pourquoi tu es venu sur ce site.

Comment: Ok je marquerais acceptée la bonne réponse après lecture et relecture profonde de l'ensemble des réponses. Merci Yohaann ton récapitulatif est très utile.

Answer (score 9):

Pour répondre à la question en tant que telle. Bien sûr qu'une phrase avec *c'est* a un sujet ! Le sujet, c'est le *c'*, qui est ici la forme élidée du pronom *cela*. Dans la phrase précédente, ce pronom renvoie au groupe nominal « le sujet ».

Comment: Le pronom ne renvoie justement pas au sujet de la phrase précédente. Comme indiqué dans ma réponse, je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de règle pour définir à quoi se rapporte le *"c'"* dans *"c'est"* et qu'il s'agit de donner plus d'information sur un élément du discours, quel qu’il soit grammaticalement.

Comment: @YohannV. L'endroit où se trouve le référent du pronom n'a absolument aucune pertinence dans la réponse à question! OrSyx nous demande si le pronom dans la formule *c'est* a un référent, et il y en a un. Qu'il soit devant, derrière, dans la même phrase ou même dans le même paragraphe (toutes situations possibles) n'a rien à y voir.

Comment: Excuse moi, j'ai mal interprété le sens de "phrase précédente", je pensais que tu parlais de *"Je vous recommande ... restau"*. Mes excuses.

Comment: Si "ce" est bien un pronom qui occupe la fonction sujet dans les phrases concernées, il n'est sans doute pas l’abréviation de cela ou de ça pour autant. Ce n'apparaît naturellement comme sujet qu'avec le verbe ÊTRE : Ce sera des spaghettis pour moi. (=Ça sera des spaghettis pour moi) ;
Ça n'arrive jamais chaud... (???Ce n'arrive jamais chaud). Ce peut être utilisé au pluriel : Ce sont des spaghettis... (??Ça sont des spaghettis).

Answer (score 4):

Un version plus professionnelle :

"Je vous recommande vivement les spaghettis bolognaise de ce restaurant, ils sont délicieux et bien épicés !"

Comment: "Bolognaise" ne prend pas un S ?!

Comment: @OSryx Non. C'est une contraction du nom long de la recette *"Spaghettis (à la (sauce)) bolognaise"*.

Answer (score 1):

Sur le *spaghetti* (subst. *masc*.) uniquement :

> ♦ *Spaghetti(s) (à la) bolo(g)naise/à la bolognese* (forme ital.).
>   Spaghettis accompagnés d'une sauce épaisse à base de légumes (céleri,
>   oignons, tomates) et de viande de bœuf hachée. *Vous avez demandé pour
>   votre déjeuner, rue de Richelieu, dans un restaurant (...), des
>   spaghetti à la bolognese, mais ce qu'on vous a apporté méritait-il
>   vraiment ce nom, ou bien était-ce la solitude dans laquelle vous vous
>   êtes senti soudain en les mangeant qui vous a empêché de les goûter,
>   de les apprécier selon leurs mérites véritables?* (Butor, *Modif.*,
>   1957, p. 60).
>
> [...]*Spaghetti* est parfois sing. en fr. (v. Dupré supra). Prop. du
>   Conseil sup. de la lang. fr. ds Doc. admin. du J.O., 6 déc. 1990: un
>   *spaghetti*, des *spaghettis*, v. p. 15, col. 1 un [*ravioli*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ravioli), des *raviolis*.[...] Mot ital. att. dep. 1845 (Carena d'apr. DEI), plur. issu avec métaph. de *spaghetto* « ficelle », dér. dimin. de *spago* «
>   fil pour ficelle », du lat. tardif *spacus* « cordon, ficelle » (v.
>   Ern.-Meillet).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi à « [spaghetti](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/spaghetti) » ]

---

Le mot est au masculin; son emploi au singulier est possible, même si généralement on recommande l'emploi de la règle du singulier et du pluriel avec un mot emprunté à une autre langue (voir [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/spaghetti/74025/difficulte), [*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8350753), [*BDL*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1030)([2](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3158)), [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=frt&srchtxt=SPAGHETTI%20BOLONAISE), *Le Petit Robert* 2005...). La majuscule est [superflue](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1280).

Answer (score 0):

Formulation pompeuse et mal écrite : le texte ressemble à une critique culinaire complaisante, le restaurant vaut le détour, non pas pour y entrer mais pour l'éviter (surtout si c'est le restaurateur qui l'a lui même écrite) !

Reformuler une critique plus crédible :

> - Les plats sont savoureux et les épices finement dosées.

Sur la carte affichée, un tout simple (si c'est la vérité) :

> - Ici spécialité de Spaghetti Bolognaise, tous les plats sont fait maisons.

... m'inviteraient à pousser la porte de cette gargote.

P.S. : Pour la grammaire lire la réponse de Circeus.

Comment: La maladresse linguistique expliquerait aisément ce que tu mets sur le compte de la malhonnêteté ;-) Mais en effet la formulation initiale est techniquement mauvaise et ne rebuterait pas que nous autres, c'est tout-à-fait certain.

Answer (score 0):

Nous savons de quel restaurant il s'agit donc nous pourrions dire:

«Je vous recommande leurs spaghetti bolognaise. Ils sont délicieux et parfaitement épicés».

Il est difficile de proposer d'autres formulations sans savoir s'il s'agit du degré de «piquant» ou du type d'épices utilisées.

Comment: Je voulais dire par _épicé_, que le plat contient des épices et des ingrédients supplémentaires qui le rendent délicieux et non _piquant_ !

Answer (score 0):

Si tu souhaites conserver une abréviation pour restaurant, mieux vaut choisir *resto* plutôt que *restau* :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Dans un contexte professionnel je n'utiliserais pas « restau », j'utiliserais « restaurant ».

« C'est », bien que souvent employé dans un contexte professionnel à l'oral, est considéré comme étant familier.

Quant à la deuxième phrase tu pourrais peut être dire

Les plats sont délicieux et bien épicés !

Comment: Merci Stéphane pour la correction.

Comment: Et on évitera d'utiliser "très délicieux", qui fait bancal. On pourra dire "vraiment délicieux" ou tout simplement "délicieux".

Comment: mais je veux pas faire reference aux PLATS mais plutot à un plat spécifique qui est les Spaghettis bolognaise :)

Comment: Dans ce cas tu peux rédiger en singulier. 
"Le plat est très délicieux et bien épicé."

Comment: Pourquoi est-que l'expression  « c'est » est considérée familière?

Comment: @sumelic Bonne question. Je ne sais pas. Je l'ai appris à l'école. Des expression comme "c'est", "comme ca", etc. sont (ou étaient) considérées non formelles.

Comment: @Elyasin Il y a une marge entre « non formel » et « familier ». Pour reprendre ce que nous avons appris à l'école, on m'a enseigné que le français se divisait en trois registres : [soutenu](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Termes_soutenus_en_fran%C3%A7ais), courant et [familier](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Termes_familiers_en_fran%C3%A7ais). De nos jours, on parle aussi de [français populaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Termes_populaires_en_fran%C3%A7ais). « C'est » n'est pas soutenu mais le familier n'est pas utilisé professionellement.

Comment: Je préfère que vous editiez la réponse au lieu de voter contre.  Correction est mieux que punition.